Postgres + Python copy data millions of records
I have two tables with cols, among others, in a PostgreSQL DB such as:
Table A:
| IdA | IdTokenStore | CodeIntegerA
| 789 | (details, "{""token-string-123""}") | <null>

Table B
| IdB | IdTokenImport | CodeIntegerB
| 456 | token-string-234 | 1234

Each with 10M records.
What would be a SQL query to copy CodeIntegerB value of Table B to CodeIntegerA in Table A, based on where IdTokenStore (text) like idTokenImport? Any specific way of doing this considering the large number of records?
How can you approach this with Python in a Jupyter notebook for example, so as to do it in parts, so you can do 500,000 or 1M at a time for example - especially if the record count is even higher?

where IdTokenStore (text) like idTokenImport if it really is just based on a like, then it is not going to quick.  Is there some patterns rather than like ?

Unfortunately not, only the like, which as you mentioned is long running

I don't understand your example. Are you suggesting token-string-123 is like token-string-234? Can you provide an example where X is like Y, where X is not like Y, and show the expected result in each case please?

You can try something like this:  https://dbfiddle.uk/hZqCngSL
